# Convert List Iteration to forEach with a condition

Tags: java

I have a list of items. I am iterating the list and if the next element is present in the list I am appending a comma and if that is the last element I am appending a "!".

Instead of using for loop, can this be done with forEach?

```
List<String> list1 = new LinkedList<>();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

list1.add("one");
list1.add("two");
list1.add("three");
list1.add("four");
list1.add("five");

for(int i=0; i<list1.size();i++) {
    sb.append(list1.get(i));
    if(i+1 < list1.size()) {
        sb.append(",");
    } else {
        sb.append("!");
    }
}
```

I tried..

```
list1.forEach(s -> {
    sb.append(s);
    if() { // not sure how to check if next element is present..
        sb.append(",");
    } else {
        sb.append("!");
    }
});
```

How to check i+1 condition within forEach...

Comment: How should an empty list be displayed? Empty string, or single `!` ?

Comment: @Aaron i will check whether the list size is greater than 0 before iterating the loop..not sure how to use i+1 within forEach

Comment: You may not need to, since once you have exited the loop you are just after the last element. All current answers rely on that fact, but it leads to outputing `!` for empty lists, which may have been incorrect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you should use the `String.join` function. Something like this:

```
String.join(",", list1) + "!"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try using streams.
A solution using Collectors.joining method:

```
list1.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")).concat("!");
```

A solution using stream reduction:

```
list1.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a.concat(",").concat(b)).map(a -> a.concat(",")).orElse("");
```

And of course if you would not like to use streams you could do the following forEach chain call.

```
list1.forEach(s -> sb.append(s).append(','));
String str = sb.toString().concat("!");
```

Comment: No need to create a `Stream` when you have the `join` function on `String`.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use 'forEach' then following would work:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",", "", "!");
list1.forEach(l -> sj.add(l));
System.out.println(sj.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1.forEach((k,s) -> {
    sb.append(s);
    if(k + 1 < list1.size()) {
        sb.append(",");
    } else {
        sb.append("!");
    }
});
```

If you want to look for other example using `forEach`, see this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-foreach-examples/).

Comment: OP is using a `List` which doesn't have a `forEach` method that takes a `BiConsumer`. What method are you using? This seems more like `list1` is a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me. If the list is empty, the StringBuffer is too, because it will not go into the foreach part.

```
list1.forEach(s -> {
    sb.append(s);
    if(list1.indexOf(s) + 1 != list1.size()) {
        sb.append(",");
    } else {
        sb.append("!");
    }
});
```